# How to deep link react-native app and open app from browser in android .I have tried intent filter in Androidmanifest.xml but nothing happened

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, deep-linking

I have also added Linking.getinitialURL() and console logged it in componentDidMount in my main react class . I am using stack navigator and used linking in first screen of it and also tried in putting in router screen nothing happened

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.letsendorseapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">//Here I added intent filter when I run http://example.com/ in chrome nothing happens 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" /> 

    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
  android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Using the Chrome search bar won't work. It *must* be a link.

Comment: @SimonMarquis I have tried in other browsers without any success also I installed the app after changing Manifest .Do I need to have a signed version of app installed for it to work . I am using 'react-native-run-android'